# How to hide text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to make `foo` invisible using CSS (CSS3 if needed) while keeping `bar` and `fizz` visible?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea>bar</textarea>
      <input type='button' title='fizz' />
      foo
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Making `foo` in the same color as background is acceptable, but the trick is - background is an image, hence - `foo` must be transparent instead of solid color.

JavaScript isn't an option either.

Changing HTML is not an option either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can the real text you're representing with "foo" be identified? That is, could you select it in javascript?

Comment: I know you accepted another answer, but you have got to check out the second part of my answer, I cannot believe it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Scott's is better. Use his.

I don't think a proper solution is going to be pretty.

```
td {
    position: relative;
    left: 9001px;
}

textarea {
    position: relative;
    right: 9001px;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. Bravo!

Comment: But what happens when somebody comes along that has a 12000px screen?  This would have been my solution also so I will vote you up.  :-)

Comment: It helped. Things look real fancy now.

Comment: Just wanted you to be aware, I discovered a better way (see second part of my answer)

Comment: @Justin, Then have some JavaScript to wrap the text and hide it.  I'm not sure we'll see 12000px displays any time soon, and by then people will probably have JS enabled anyway.

Answer (score 9):

This worked fine in IE8 and Firefox (IE7 left little dots for words, which I guess if you set the `font-color` to something that blends with the background image, it might do fine. Note that this does not affect either the `text-area` or the `input` for any text in them.

```
td {font-size: 0;}
```

*ADDED ON EDIT*

**WOW** I mean, really! This worked on IE7-8, Firefox, and Safari

```
td {visibility: hidden}
td textarea,
td input {visibility: visible;}
```

As a side note, I tested this with elements wrapped in `div` rather than a table, I even did a `div` in a `div` and the inner `div` shows while other content is hidden.

Apparently, the `visibility` property acts on the element, and (unlike `opacity`) propagates to the child elements by inheritance, so that if one explicitly sets a child element `visibility` it no longer inherits the `hidden` but uses its own setting of `visible` and the fact that the wrapper is `hidden` does not matter.

Comment: This is vaguely what I thought of, but I reasoned you can't re-visible-ize a child element.  I guess you can...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to support IE then setting the text to transparent is easy:

```
table {
    background-color: cyan;
}
td {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
td textarea, td input {
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it inside a container like a **div** then hide the container ..

Comment: Sorry... Forgot to mention that can't change html either. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of the `td` to be the same as the size of the `textarea` (via CSS `width` and `height`), then set `overflow: hidden` on the TD so that the text you want to hide is outside the bounding box?

Comment: That might work... There's button before `foo`. I guess it must be set to display:block, right (some padding-bottom maybe)?

Comment: If you know the size of the button, you could add that to the size of the TD (and yes, set the button to block, so that the text will get pushed down below it).

Answer (score 0):

whoops... should've read the OP a bit more closely. Guess the following won't work after all, since changing the html isn't an option.

Set a css class on the container you want to hide (the textarea?):

```
...
   <textarea class="hideme">bar</textarea>
...
```

and the following css:

```
.hideme {
   display: hidden;
}
```

'hidden' makes the element disappear (it's literally not displayed), but still is still accounted for in the document flow and takes up the space it normally would. If you want it to literally be gone and not have any effect on the document, then use `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

How about the reverse of [Amber's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber) suggestion -

Set overflow to `overflow: hidden` on the TD, fix the size where it is right now and add a huge `padding-bottom` on the `textarea` or `button`.

Comment: Don't know. Fixed with `position:relative`. Too lazy to check out. :)